# In Python, how do I plot a color-coded 2-D graph (X, Y, color) for inequally-spaced / random y values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm plotting something similar to a spectogram. I have some 1D arrays of length N, each of which corresponds to one 'horizontal line' in a 2D graph. For a spectogram [M,N], I would need M such N-length arrays to fill all M horizontal lines.

However, I only have data for a smaller number of lines. Let's say I have m < M arrays. These don't correspond to equal-spaced values in the y axis. They're random values. For example, I might only have arrays corresponding to lines 6, 44, 44.5 and 92 (where M=4).

I want to have the y axis from 0 to 100, and plot these lines of values for only the y-values I have, and 0 otherwise. How do I do this?

If I had arrays for y values that are equally spaced on the Y axis, I can do this:

```py
 y_values = np.array(M) # ticks for y axis - equal-spaced. eg: [2, 2.5, 3, 3.5]. These are the only values for which data exists.
 get_y_values(y_values)
 data = np.array([M,N])
 get_data(data)

 fig = pyplot.figure()
 vmax = np.amax(data)
 ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
 ax.imshow(data, origin='lower', aspect='auto', vmin=0, vmax=vmax)

 ax.set_xlabel('Time')
 ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
 ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, y_values.size))
 ax.set_yticklabels(yvalues)

 pyplot.show()
```

But it won't work for random y-values, as they'll appear equal-spaced -when they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, but a quick and easy way would be to loop over each time series and plot them individually.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M = 4
N = 100
dy = 2.0 # The desired vertical thickness of each line

y_values = np.arange(0,100)

y_values = [6, 44, 47, 92]
x = np.arange(0, N)
data = np.random.rand(M,N)

fig = plt.figure()
vmax = np.amax(data)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

for i in range(M):
    ax.pcolor(x, [y_values[i], y_values[i] + dy], [data[i],data[i]], vmin=0, vmax=vmax)

ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_yticks(y_values)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)

plt.show()
```

[Here's a link to the output figure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbDuC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I set out to solve the problem of filling in the missing data points. This code assumes you want a list of xs from 0 to 100 and that you already have a few xs and a few corresponding ys. It then fills in the rest of the xs and sets their corresponding y values to 0. After that, it orders them by x values, zips, and prints. I figured you can adapt this from here. Hopefully, I haven't misunderstood.

```
current_xs = [6, 44, 44.5, 92] #the x values
current_ys = [7, 2, 45, 5] #corresponding y values I made up

def fill(current_xs, current_ys):
    for i in range(0, 200):
        if i/2 not in current_xs:
            current_xs.append(i/2)
            current_ys.append(0)
    total = list(zip(current_xs, current_ys))
    total = sorted(total, key=lambda x: x[0])
    print(total)

fill(current_xs, current_ys)
```